# Ignore First Row in DataFrame CSVread

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to build a fairly simple script that will compare two DataFrames from a CSV and perform an inner merge to remove duplicates. Now I noticed that one of my CSVs looks like this:

```
Row [0]: One column
Row [1:]: 2+ columns
```

Now, when I try to import it via pandas.csv_read(...) I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 391, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 207, in _read
return parser.read()
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 624, in read
ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas-0.10.0-py2.7-macosx-10.5-i386.egg/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 945, in read
data = self._reader.read(nrows)
File "parser.pyx", line 634, in pandas._parser.TextReader.read (pandas/src/parser.c:5795)
File "parser.pyx", line 656, in pandas._parser.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/src/parser.c:6015)
File "parser.pyx", line 734, in pandas._parser.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/src/parser.c:6892)
File "parser.pyx", line 791, in pandas._parser.TextReader._convert_column_data (pandas/src/parser.c:7596)
File "parser.pyx", line 1015, in pandas._parser.TextReader._get_column_name (pandas/src/parser.c:10425)
```

I assume this has to do with the first row, as when I delete it the problem is gone. How can I ignore such errors and just fill the rest with empty values?

Best,
Oliver

Comment: its `pandas.read_csv` and you pass it `skiprows=1` to skip the first row

Comment: But is there a way to automatically do it? Maybe someone has a file where the first TWO rows need to be skipped.

Comment: You can skiprows with a variable (hard to say how to do it automatically without more info)...

Answer (score 0):

I think the right answer is that you can't, in general.  `csv_read` expects input to be well-formed.  Everyone might want different behavior when you go outside of expected inputs.  For example, if your input looks like this:

```
0
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

One person may want to ignore the first row, another may want to fill NA values in for the two missing columns of the first row, and another person may want to just read the first column (inferring there is only one column from the first row, and ignoring excess values on subsequent rows).  All three solutions are reasonable, so it is best to leave data cleanup to the user.

That being said, if you post more information about the sort of input you are trying to cleanup, I'm sure someone here can help you out.